# Why is there no camera attached, even if I've attached it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

So, i want to use camera.ViewportToWorldPoint() to show the **bottom center** bounds of my screen. So, I created a script, add that component to my object that need it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PathMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera cam;
    private Vector3 bound;

    void Awake () {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera> ();
    }

    void Start(){
        bound = cam.ViewportToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (0f, 0.5f));
        Debug.Log (bound);
    }
}
```

and then, I attach the `MainCamera` via the GUI

[image]

And then, when I run it, there's still an error says :

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'Camera' attached to the "RiverPath" game object, but a >script is trying to access it.
>   You probably need to add a Camera to the game object "RiverPath". Or your script needs to check if >the component is attached before using it.
>   UnityEngine.Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint (Vector3 position) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineCamera.gen.cs:408)
>   PathMovement.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/PathMovement.cs:21)

This is quite weird since I've attached the main camera, but somehow unity didn't detect that. I also have tried to put the `cam = GetComponent<Camera>();` on `Awake()` as well as `Start()`, but none work. :(

Btw, I am making a mobile application on android. And using unity 5.

Is there any way to do it properly?? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the `MissingComponentException` as there is no `Camera` attached to that particular GameObject (see the description of the Exception).

What you need to know is that `GetComponent` only looks for that `Component` in the current GameObject. Depending on your GameObject hierarchy you may want to use [GetComponentInParent](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInParent.html) or [GetComponentInChildren](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html) instead.

Or you could also attach the Camera using the Editor (drag and drop). This may not work if you instantiate that Prefab during runtime, but should do just fine when its static in the scene.

Comment: yeah. I somehow drag-drop the camera & calling the GetComponent<Camera>() afterards. Thanks tho